# Netezza - update one table with max data from another table

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table in netezza that I need to update. The columns I am working with are

**TABLE A**

- ID_NO
- ENTRY_DATE
- PRICE

**TABLE B**

- ID_NO
- START_DATE
- END_DATE
- PRICE

So an example of the data would look like this:

**TABLE A**

| ID_NO | ENTRY_DATE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-05-01 |  |
| 123 | 2020-08-15 |  |

**TABLE B**

| ID_NO | START_DATE | END_DATE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-11-01 | $7.64 |
| 123 | 2020-04-30 | 2020-05-02 | $6.19 |
| 123 | 2020-04-15 | 2020-08-30 | $2.19 |

I need to update the PRICE in TABLE A to be the max PRICE from TABLE B where a.ENTRY_DATE is between b.START_DATE and b.END_DATE. So the final table should look like this:

**TABLE A**

| ID_NO | ENTRY_DATE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-05-01 | $6.19 |
| 123 | 2020-08-15 | $2.19 |

This is what I have so far, but it just ends up taking the max price that fits either row rather than doing the calculation for each row:

```
update TABLE_A
set PRICE=(select max(b.PRICE) 
            from TABLE_B b
            inner join TABLE_A a on a.ID_NO=b.ID_NO
            where a.ENTRY_DATE between b.START_DATE and b.END_DATE)
```

Comment: Your example query has confusing mistakes in the `WHERE` clause.   For example; neither `b.ENTRY_DATE` or `a.START_DATE` exist.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. Fixed the table references on that clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to Netezza, but a usual format would be to use a correlated sub-query.

That is, instead of including `TABLE_A` again in the query, you refer to the outer reference to `TABLE_A`...

```
update
  TABLE_A
set
  PRICE = (
    select max(b.PRICE) 
      from TABLE_B b
     where TABLE_A.ID_NO         =    b.ID_NO
       and TABLE_A.ENTRY_DATE between b.START_DATE and b.END_DATE
  )
```

In this way, the correlated-sub-query is essentially invoked once for each row in `TABLE_A` and that invocation uses the current row from `TABLE_A` as its parameters.

An alternative could be...

```
update
  TABLE_A
set
  PRICE = revised.PRICE
from
(
      select a.ID_NO, a.ENTRY_DATE, max(b.PRICE) AS PRICE
        from TABLE_B b
  inner join TABLE_A a on a.ID_NO=b.ID_NO
       where a.ENTRY_DATE between b.START_DATE and b.END_DATE
    group by a.ID_NO, a.ENTRY_DATE
)
  AS revised
where
      TABLE_A.ID_NO      = revised.ID_NO
  and TABLE_A.ENTRY_DATE = revised.ENTRY_DATE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, the correlated sub-query isn't supported, which is part of the reason I'm having so much trouble with this piece.

Comment: @eric Alternative added to the answer.

Comment: I think that might have worked! I need to do some testing on the larger data set, but it looks promising.

Comment: It looks like that did the trick. Thanks a ton!